# Is it possible to send two ajax request from client asynchronous to the server?

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous, request

My situation is that i have a page and the seller is going to take the order of a client, after the client orders, the seller hits the confirm button and awaits for the client to pass his identification card, wich i do with a ajax request and pop up a dialog with the list of products, a message and a cancel button.

After my ajax is sended in the server side, i'm doing a 'for' with a 'sleep' to check if the user has passed his card and then if he has, i put the items into his bill (persist into the database). The problem is, if that the user decides to cancel de proccess, i can't get the cancel ajax request to work because its busy with the first request on the server side and waiting its return.

Anyone have nay suggestions on that? I really wanted that the workflow of the site works like this:

Client orders -> Seller add the items and hits confirm -> Client passes confirmation  or Seller can Cancel -> End of procces

Comment: Instead of "waiting" for the client to submit his card, why not create a process that performs an operation WHEN he submits his card?

Comment: In other words, have a script that the client submits a form to, which THEN processes the data. There shouldn't be any need for a listener.

Comment: The problem is, how i'm going to know if the proccess has finished so i can close the dialog? With the ajax return, when the method returns i know that it is finished, otherwise how would i know?

Comment: Your script would send a "success" message to your ajax call, either by JSON or with a simple 1 or 0.

Comment: And the items are being stored in the client $_SESSION, so with the ajax approach i can handle it easily with that. The submit of the client part comes from a other device, wich will have a differente $_SESSION

Comment: If when he hits confirm i open a dialog with ajax, how is that another request is going to return success to my ajax method?

Comment: Yes, that's how sessions work. Take a look at @Ioannis' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even if there was a simple way to do it the way you are going about it, this process would quickly overwhelm the server after more than a handful of connections.

I would store the customer's order to the database before requiring his identification, with a status field on the order set to "Awaiting Identification", or something to that effect. Then you can proceed with the identification flow without having to hold the PHP script waiting, and conserving a lot of resources.

If the client inadvertedly disconnects, you will still have saved her order and can allow her to complete identification at a later time.

Finally, when the client successfully completes identification, you can simply update the order 's status field to "authenticated" to indicate it's ready for processing.

---

EDIT: To address your particular problem, consider the following flow:

1. You save the order as "pending identification" and display the "Waiting..." dialog.
2. You perform a really simple request every few seconds asking whether the status of the order has changed, to know when the dialog needs closing.
3. At some point, the identification device sends a confirmation request upon which you retrieve the order and change its status. Then the periodic call you implemented in step 2 will kick in and hide the dialog.

The session is not a good location as a temporary storage medium, but a Redis, Memcached or similar service could help you simplify that process, given that the device and the site can in some way share information.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was trying to say, but couldn't get the wording right (haven't had my coffee yet).

Comment: Ok, even if i do that, i dont hold the server when i hit the confirm button, but i will pop up a dialog saying 'Waiting for id'. When the client passes his id, it comes from a another session request and then after it finish how am i gonna know that i can close the dialog? With that approach i have the close dialog problem.

Comment: The confirmation comes from a eletronic sensor device thats going to send a post/get request to my server with some ids so i can know from wich sensor the request came.

Comment: Check out my answer, I have updated according to your latest comments.

Comment: The problem with me is that i was making the server side to check with sleep and that would freeze the server for that session. Now i'm making the client side check if it has been updated and then closes de dialog and i still can get the cancel effect.

Comment: You will have to structure your flow in discrete steps, and go from there. What I mean is that, to avoid having the server wait for a particular thing to happen, you must always poll for the order 's state, and act accordingly.